# Bootstrap Dropdown links not working mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the following site: [rosslote.eu](http://rosslote.eu) you will see a menu item called "setup". This menu item has a dropdown. The dropdown works perfectly on a desktop, but as soon as it is loaded onto a mobile the links in the setup dropdown stop working. The only thing they do is collapse the dropdown.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="top-level nav">
    <li class="dropdown ">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">setup<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="level-1 dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/#/">database</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/">info</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/">images</a></li>
        <li><a href="/opening-times/">opening times</a></li>
        <li><a href="/google/">google</a></li>
        <li><a href="/meta/">meta</a></li>
        <li><a href="/article-editor/">main article</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/plugins/">plugins</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the following script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Again, this achieves the desired result on my desktop but not on a mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include bootstrap-responsive.css as bootstrap-combined doesn't contain it

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it. I find that really strange though. The responsiveness was working so the combined one must have some sort of responsive css in it. Anyway, thanks.